# How to increment date up to a certain date for inserting data?

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I have a prepared statement like the one below inserting it to a `postgres` database:

```
 String InsertQuery="INSERT INTO public.user_daily_activity (id,user,day,time) 
 values (?,?,?,?)";
 String date="2017-11-16";
try{
   jtmTemplate.update(InsertQuery, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
   public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
   preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
   preparedStatement.setString(2, user);
   preparedStatement.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
   preparedStatement.setInt(4, time);

}
```

So now depending on the date I need to increment it from the start date to November 30. For example if date=`"2017-11-16"` then I need to insert from `"2017-11-16" to "2017-11-30"`. If date=`"2017-11-27"` then I need to insert from `"2017-11-27"` to  `"2017-11-30"`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don’t do it in prepared statement. Do it in your java code

Comment: What do u mean?If i am not wrong keep the prepared statement in a loop right

Comment: No that is not wrong. But you ask *How can I do it in prepared statement*

Comment: Sorry the heading was misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here you have a solution using pre-java8 `Date` and `Calendar`:

```
public void incrementDate() {
    int dayLimit = 30;
    // month is zero-based index
    int monthLimit = 10;
    String startStringDate = "2017-11-16";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date startDate;
    java.sql.Date sqlDate;
    try {
        startDate = dateFormat.parse(startStringDate);
        calendar.setTime(startDate);
        while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= dayLimit && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) <= monthLimit) {
            sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime());
            // here just use sqlDate in your prepared statement
            //...
            //e.g. preparedStatement.setDate(3, sqlDate);
            // ...
            System.out.println("Using sql date : " + sqlDate);
            calendar.setTime(startDate);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            startDate = calendar.getTime();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```